# Changing concatenated date to datetime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have an `int` value that I've parsed through a series of string dates in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
last_date_daily = int(old_df_daily.iloc[2,-1])
print(last_date_daily)
```

Which gives:

```
20190106
```

I simply want to convert this integer to a datetime format.

I've tried:

```
last_date_daily = pd.to_datetime(last_date_daily)
```

Which leaves me with a swap of time to date and an incorrect date:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190106
```

Is there an easy way to make this conversion without having to split the year, month, and day by a `-` or `/` string?

Comment: Try pd.to_datetime(last_date_daily.astype(str))

Comment: This works! But since it's an `integer` it has no attribute `astype` so I had to use `last_date_daily = pd.to_datetime(str(last_date_daily))` instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/).

```
import dateparser
dateparser.parse('20190106', date_formats=['%Y%m%d'])
>>> datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6, 0 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

to_datetime handles this case for strings:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime('20190106')
Out[11]: Timestamp('2019-01-06 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really not hard to break an integer into different fields.

```
>>> datetime.datetime(last_date_daily//10000, (last_date_daily//100)%100, last_date_daily%100)
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be casting your integer to a string before calling `to_datetime()` on it. It should be:

```
last_date_daily = pd.to_datetime(str(last_date_daily))
```